# One ball with two momenta

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

In the [ADAM](https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Adam) optimization algorithm, I think of the solution as being modeled as a ball with two momenta.

Is it ever possible for a real ball to have two momenta?

I have three proposed situations where a ball can have two momenta:

1. Imagine a marble rolling down a loop-the-loop. This corresponds to the case where there is one momentum. Now, imagine building a roller coaster that is an exact replica of the marble track, then imagine picking the loop-the-loop track up and taking it on the rollercoaster, and perfectly timing the release of the roller coaster and the marble so they follow the same path. Then, since the roller coaster has it's own momentum, it seems like this might impart two momenta on the balls, since the roller coaster will have it's own momentum which I think should impact the path of the ball.
2. Say the ball we're looking at is called Ball A, and is made of a thick shell. Inside, I have a second ball, Ball B, which is inside Ball A. Ball B is small and solid. Ball B is snugly packed into Ball A, and is able to roll with zero friction inside ball B.
3. Say the balls in case 2 are magnetic, and Ball B is much more magnetic than Ball A. If the balls are driven be a changing magnetic field, I think they should have two momenta

Are both of these OK interpretations? Is it possible for a ball to have two momenta?

In my thought experiment, the ball is rolling down a landscape. The ADAM optimization algorithm is based on a simpler algorithm which gives the solution inertia, and (I think) translates perfectly to the ball analogy:

$
v_t = \vec{v}_{t-1} m + (1-m) \nabla{f}(x_{t-1}) 
$

$
x_t = x_{t-1} + \vec{v}\Delta t 
$

where $\Delta t$ is the learning rate in the ADAM optimization algorithm and, $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the ball, $\nabla f$ is the slope of the ground, $x$ is the position of the ball, and $m\in]0,1[$ is the mass of the ball.

The adam optimization algorithm operates in a world where balls can have two momenta, as in, there are two $\vec{v}$ terms that are updated differently with different masses. Can the ball analogy still work here?

(Appendix)

The complete ADAM algorithm is as follows. I am thinking of a case where $t$ is small and $m_1$ and $m_2$ are very close to $1$.

initialize $x_0$, $m_1$, $m_2$

$\vec{v}_1 \leftarrow \vec{0}$

$\vec{v}_2 \leftarrow \vec{0}$

$x=x_0$

for $t$ in $1, \dots, N_t$

do

$ \ \ \ \ \vec{v}_1 = m_1 \vec{v_1} + (1 - m_1) \nabla f(x)$

$  \ \ \ \ \vec{v}_2 = m_2 \vec{v_2} + (1 - m_2) \nabla f(x)^2$

$ \ \ \ \ \hat{\vec{v}}_1 = \vec{v}_1 / (1 - m_1^t) $

$ \ \ \ \ \hat{\vec{v}}_2 = \vec{v}_2 / (1 - m_2^t) $

$ \ \ \ \  x = x - \Delta t \left(
                \dfrac{\hat{\vec{v}}_1}
                     {\sqrt{\hat{\vec{v}}_2}}
                 \right) $

done

Comment: Are you conflating the usage of the word *moment* (and the unfortunately named method *momentum*) with momentum? The latter meaning mass times velocity while the former, in the context of ADAM, indicate the [moment of the vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Notable_moments) (specifically the [mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean) and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance))

Comment: The simpler case, with one velocity term, has one momentum, $m \vec{v}$. ADAM has two: $m_1 \vec{v}_1$ and $m_2 \vec{v}_2$.  The way I'm thinking, momentum itself is a moving average (moment) of mass times velocity?

Comment: No, I think you are misunderstanding the terms used in the ADAM method. It is the first and second moments of the vector, generally called mean and variance. Nothing to do with masses or velocities here.

Comment: Does the first equation not match a ball rolling down a hill? I think the $\nabla f$ term would be acceleration from gravity

Comment: A linear equation, $y=mx+b$ also matches the kinematic equation, $u=v+at$, does that mean all linear equations are the same as the change in velocity due to an acceleration? No, not really. Note also that in one case you have $\nabla f$ and in the second equation you have $(\nabla f)^2$, which is different (in your weak analogy, this would be more akin to a kinetic energy, I guess?)

Comment: But I still think that the point remains that you are misinterpreting the meaning of the terms. You should spend some time reviewing the links I provided in my first comment.

Comment: @KyleKanos Several have used the momentum analogy, e.g., footnote 18 here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.5533v2.pdf. If you don't like it you can move on, there is no need to insult my analogy or suggest I don't know those simple definitions.

Comment: The ball & hill analogy works in the sense that you are trying to find a global/local minimum of the field, much how a ball will roll down to minimize its potential energy. Trying to use that to say that a ball has two momenta is over-extending the analogy. The ADAM method uses the mean and variance of an arbitrary array to minimize the array vs the loss function, that's all there is to it.